# Return error number

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to return error number using PostgreSQL 9.3 Version.

I referred this :-> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html

but want to know how do I return the error number.

In SQL Server 2008 R2 we just use `@@ERROR`..

**Example**:

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Error message';
   RETURN(1);
END
```

**My Question**: Can we get error number in PostgreSQL like we get in SQL Server by using `@@ERROR`?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PL/pgSQL, you must [trap errors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) and you can [raise](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) (custom) errors. (Normal execution is stopped during an error.)

Errors in PostgreSQL has levels, [error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) (`SQLSTATE`) and explicit names.

F.ex:

```
BEGIN
    -- code that can potentially raise an error
EXCEPTION
    WHEN division_by_zero THEN -- trap by name
        -- handle division_by_zero
    WHEN SQLSTATE '22012' THEN -- trap by SQLSTATE
        -- handle SQLSTATE 22012
    WHEN OTHERS THEN -- trap all other error
        RAISE no_data; -- raise error by name
        RAISE SQLSTATE '02000'; -- raise error by SQLSTATE
END
```